# Django Rest Framework: Embed Viewset Inside Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following two Django models (simplified for this example).

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    study_id = models.IntegerField()
    ... 
    # Lots of other fields

class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()
    participant = models.ForeignKey('Participant')
```

Using Django Rest Framework I have set up a `ModelSerializer` and `ModelViewSet` for each model. Using the `@detail_route` and `@list_route` decorators I have set up the following URLs.

```
/api/participant/ (GET,POST for list and create)
/api/participant/:study_id (GET,PUT for retrieve and update)
/api/participant/:study_id/messages (GET for list POST to send message)
```

I would like to add the following url for changing message meta data. This will make working with the API much easier in `restangular`

```
/api/participant/:study_id/messages/:msg_id (PATCH partial update of message)
```

It would be nice to have a way to embed a `Message` ViewSet inside the `Participant` since this would make the logic for GET and POST on messages simpler as well.  Is this possible? If not how can I pass the msg_id to a @detail_rouet on messages?

Comment: Check out DRF nested routers. https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of nested routers. Beside the one already mentioned, I will name https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions

Personally, I've used Restangular with drf-extensions. Comes with caching support.

Two hints on how to enable nested routing:

- you must declare in your viewset the model on which it operates
- you must follow the nested router definition correctly.